# Get Normal Font Style in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, vsto, powerpoint

I'm trying to check a presentation for the fonts that exist in it. This can be done with `ActivePresentation.Fonts`. I also want to check if the font is normal, bold and/or italic. Bold and Italic are easy, but Normal is not. For example, say I have two text boxes, one of them has "Hello World" in Arial Italic and another the same in Arial Bold. The following code tells me I have both of these:

```
Sub CheckFonts()
    Dim p As Presentation: Set p = ActivePresentation
    Dim f As Font: Set f = p.Fonts(1)
    Dim italic As Boolean: italic = f.italic
    Dim bold As Boolean: bold = f.bold
    Debug.Print "Bold in use: " & bold; vbTab & "Italic in use: " & italic
End Sub
```

Now let's assume I have one of the textboxes without Italic, but instead it is just normal Arial font. Without looping through every single font object in all shapes, is there anyway I can tell that it is a normal font (i.e. no formatting of italic/bold applied) from `Presentation.Fonts`?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry this is **not an answer**, but too funny to not pass on. During my little research for your Fonts problem I came upon the [MSDN reference page for the Fonts object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb265518%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Apparently someone at Microsoft works for Genigraphics or someone copied documentation from some other product...

[image]

Here the excerpt preserved for eternity:

> The Fonts collection is used by the Geni Wizard to determine whether any
>   of the fonts in the specified
>   presentation won't be supported when
>   Genigraphics images the slides. If you
>   just want to set character formatting
>   for a particular bullet or text range,
>   use the Font property to return the
>   Font object for the bullet or text
>   range.
>
> The Genigraphics wizard enables users
>   to transmit their presentations
>   directly to Genigraphics for
>   conversion into film slides, overhead
>   transparencies, or other specialized
>   media formats. For more information
>   about the services Genigraphics
>   provides, visit the Genigraphics Web
>   site. This service may not be
>   available outside the United States.

What the hell is that text doing on MSDN? :-)

Comment: Genigraphics was instrumental in developing PowerPoint. https://books.google.com/books?id=t3INw5KknpYC&q=genigraphics#v=snippet&q=genigraphics&f=false

Comment: [Genigraphics: Partnership with Microsoft and development of PowerPoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genigraphics#Partnership_with_Microsoft_and_development_of_PowerPoint)